# Problem with CS50 Resize (less) - only resizes horizontally

Tags: c, resize, cs50

I'm doing the CS50 course and have been stuck on this task for some weeks now.  I felt I'd had a little epiphany regarding the code, but have hit a stumbling block.  My code resizes the image size correctly, but only uses the top half of the image, so effectively just resizes sideways, leaving the bottom half blank.

My code is below, any insights would be great!

Thank you...

```
// Copies a BMP file

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bmp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./resize n infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // extract resize factor, convert to float
    float factor = atof(argv[1]);

    // remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[2];
    char *outfile = argv[3];

    // open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

    // open output file
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 3;
    }

    // read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 4;
    }

    // determine padding for scanlines
    int padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

    //convert sizes by input factor
    int oldbiwidth = bi.biWidth;
    int oldbiheight = bi.biHeight;
    int oldpadding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
    int oldbisizeimage = ((sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) * bi.biWidth) + padding) * abs(bi.biHeight);
    int oldbfsize = bi.biSizeImage + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    bi.biWidth *= factor; //convert to new image width
    bi.biHeight *= factor; //convert to new image height
    padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
    bi.biSizeImage = ((sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) * bi.biWidth) + padding) * abs(bi.biHeight); //convert to new file size in bytes, including pixels and padding
    bf.bfSize = bi.biSizeImage + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); //convert to new file size in bytes, including pixels, padding & headers

    // write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // iterate over infile's scanlines
    for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(oldbiheight); i < biHeight; i++)
    {
        // iterate over pixels in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < oldbiwidth; j++)
        {
            // temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            for (int k = 0; k < factor; k++)
            {
                // write RGB triple to outfile
                fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
            }
        }

        // skip over padding, if any
        fseek(inptr, oldpadding, SEEK_CUR);

        // then add it back (to demonstrate how)
        for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }
    }

    // close infile
    fclose(inptr);

    // close outfile
    fclose(outptr);

    // success
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better to open bitmap files with `"rb"` and `"wb"`.

Comment: @chux - thank you for replying. the problem set provides you with the basic code from a copy function and I'm required to edit that in such a way as to make it resize.  a lot of the base function - loading etc - has already been written in for me.

Comment: If you're scaling up by a constant factor, you need to not only write `n` output pixels for each input, but also `n` output lines for each input line.  A more flexible approach would be to read the whole input file into memory, then iterate over the output pixels instead--that would also make it easier to scale with interpolation as well rather than just duplicating pixels.